# Is it haram to watch hentai and ecchi anime if you skip the inappropriate scenes and not be draw to it?

Tags: halal-haram

I like watching anime but these days more and more ecchi and hentai anime are pooping up and i was wondering if it was haram to watch these types of anime but skip on the inappropriate scenes and not be drawn to the characters?

Comment: Thank you my brother but what about ecchi anime??

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is still haram because one it’s hentai and you will always see that and there’s music. Now a days everything has music just stay away from it. It may seem hard at first to give up the things you love but I promise you if you give up the Haram acts and repent from it Allah will be very happy with you and will forgive you this is a good opportunity, Ramadan is coming soon. And Allah could grab your neck out of the hell fire. Just stay away from this and Allah will be pleased. Allah knows best.

Comment: Imam al-Ghazzali, reported that music is permitted, saying: “All these Ahadith are reported by al-Bukhari and singing and playing are not haram.” Please edit your answer correspondingly.